# Angular 8 FormArray index data is not updating

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular8, angular-reactive-forms, react-final-form-arrays

I'm trying to create dynamic from groups based on initial data with filled content and add/remove from groups. Unfortunately it is not working.

**Expected behavior is,**

- Coutry dropdown would be loaded with data and highlighted with selected value which is working fine already.
- Selected country states dropdown data should be loaded by default with selected value from initial data `stateCode` and when changing the country too which is not working currently.
- While clicking the add button, by default "United states" country and respective states data should be loaded. States dropdown should be selected by default with "--select--".

Note: All data will be coming from API. Testing purpose I have added static objects for Countries and States.

[image]

Here my attempt

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-app-example-fkjzfe-wekubn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

**Current behaviour demo**

https://angular-8-app-example-fkjzfe.stackblitz.io/

**HTML**

```
  <form [formGroup]='entityForm'>
              <div formArrayName="optionGroups" class="ui-g ui-g-12 ui-g-nopad " >
                <div  style="width: 100%;
    display: flex; margin-bottom:10px" class="ui-g  ui-g-12 ui-g-nopad " *ngFor="let item of entityForm.controls['optionGroups'].controls; let $index=index" [formGroup]="item">        
                  <div class="ui-md-4">                   
                    <label class="mandatory"
                  >Country
                  <span class="colon"></span>
                </label>
                <select formControlName="country" class="ui-inputtext" (change)="onCountryChange(entityForm.controls['optionGroups'].controls[$index].controls['country'].value, $index)" > 
                  <option>--Select--</option>
                  <option *ngFor="let c of countries" [ngValue]="c.countryCode">{{c.country}}</option>                 
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="ui-md-4">

                <label class="lbl-hidden"> State </label>
                <select formControlName="state" class="ui-inputtext"> 
                  <option>--Select--</option>
                  <option *ngFor="let state of states[entityForm.controls['optionGroups'].controls[$index].controls['country'].value]" value="state.code">{{state.state}}</option>
              </select>
              </div>
              <div class="ui-md-3">
                <label class="lbl-hidden"> Number </label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  pInputText
                  class="form-control"
                  formControlName="place"    
                />
                </div>
                <div class="ui-md-1">
                 
                  <button (click)='removeOptionGroup(i)'  style="min-width: auto;"  pButton icon="fa fa-minus">Remove</button>
                </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>        
            <button class="add-remove-btn" pButton (click)='addOptionGroup()' icon="fa fa-plus">Add</button>`
```

**TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core'

import { FormBuilder, Validators, FormArray, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  public countryOptions:any = [];
  public stateOptions:any = [];

  public countries = [];
  public states = [];

  public entityForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.entityForm = this.fb.group({
    optionGroups : this.fb.array([]),
});

this.countries = this.countryOptions
this.states=[];
}


public addOptionGroup(){

  const fa = this.entityForm.controls["optionGroups"] as FormArray;
   //fa.setValue("--Select--");
  fa.push(this.newOptionGroup());


  }

  public removeOptionGroup(index: number){

    const fa = this.entityForm.controls["optionGroups"] as FormArray;
  
    fa.removeAt(index);
  
    }

    onCountryChange(selectedCountry: string , formIndex : number) : void {
      this.states[selectedCountry] = this.getStates(selectedCountry)
    }

    private newOptionGroup() {
      return new FormGroup({          
          country: new FormControl("--select--"),
          state: new FormControl("--select--"),
          place: new FormControl("GGG"),

      });
  }


  getStates(selectedCountry) {
    //API call

    switch(selectedCountry) {
      case "US" : 
        this.stateOptions =[
      {id: 14, state: "Alabama", code: "AL", countryCode: "US"},
      {id: 15, state: "Alaska", code: "AK", countryCode: "US"},
      {id: 17, state: "Arizona", code: "AZ", countryCode: "US"},
      {id: 18, state: "Arkansas", code: "AR", countryCode: "US"},
      {id: 19, state: "California", code: "CA", countryCode: "US"}
      ]
      break;

     case  "CA" :
       this.stateOptions =[{id: 37, state: "Marshall Islands", code: "MH", countryCode: "CA"},
      {id: 4, state: "New Brunswick", code: "NB", countryCode: "CA"},
      {id: 5, state: "Newfoundland and Labrador", code: "NL", countryCode: "CA"},
      {id: 53, state: "Northern Mariana Islands", code: "MP", countryCode: "CA"},
      {id: 6, state: "Northwest Territories", code: "NT", countryCode: "CA"}]
      break;    
    default: 
     this.stateOptions =[
      {id: 14, state: "Alabama", code: "AL", countryCode: "US"},
      {id: 15, state: "Alaska", code: "AK", countryCode: "US"},
      {id: 17, state: "Arizona", code: "AZ", countryCode: "US"},
      {id: 18, state: "Arkansas", code: "AR", countryCode: "US"},
      {id: 19, state: "California", code: "CA", countryCode: "US"}
      ]
      break;
  }
    return this.stateOptions;

   }

   initFormArray(initForm:any) {
    const formArray = this.entityForm.get('optionGroups') as FormArray;
    initForm.map((item, index) => {
      formArray.push(this.createForms(item, index));
    });
    this.entityForm.setControl('optionGroups', formArray);
   }

   createForms(adresse, index): FormGroup {
   
    let formGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup(
      {
        country: new FormControl(adresse.countryCode),
        state: new FormControl(adresse.stateCode),
        place: new FormControl(adresse.fileNumber)
      }
    );
 this.onCountryChange(adresse.select1, index)
    return formGroup;
  }


  
 getAllCountries() {
   //API call
   this.countries = [{"country":"United States","countryCode":"US"},{"country":"Canada","countryCode":"CA"}]
 }
  

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllCountries()
    const initData = [
      {countryCode: "US", stateCode: "AZ", fileNumber: "AAA"},
      {countryCode: "CA", stateCode: null, fileNumber: null}
    ]

    this.initFormArray(initData)
  }

}
```

Comment: Updated the post with my code. same available in stackblitz.

Answer (score 1):

I symplified you scripts and seems work as due. But it's not finish - all may be done much more pretty. Pay attention to the formation html part - [formGroupName]="i" and how to work with formArray variable.

```
//html
<form [formGroup]="entityForm">
  <div formArrayName="optionGroups" class="ui-g ui-g-12 ui-g-nopad">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of optionGroups.controls; let i = index;" [formGroupName]="i">
      <div style="width: 100%; display: flex; margin-bottom:10px" class="ui-g  ui-g-12 ui-g-nopad">
        <div class="ui-md-4">
          <label class="mandatory">Country <span class="colon"></span></label>
          <select 
            formControlName="country"
            class="ui-inputtext" 
            (change)="onCountryChange(item.get('country').value, i)" 
            > 
            <option>--Select--</option>
            <option *ngFor="let c of countries" [ngValue]="c.countryCode">{{c.country}}</option>                 
          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="ui-md-4">
          <label class="lbl-hidden"> State </label>
          <select formControlName="state" class="ui-inputtext"> 
            <option>--Select--</option>
            <option *ngFor="let state of getStates(item.controls['country'].value)" [ngValue]="state.code">{{state.state}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="ui-md-3">
          <label class="lbl-hidden"> Number </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            pInputText
            class="form-control"
            formControlName="place"    
          />
        </div>
        <div class="ui-md-1">     
          <button (click)='removeOptionGroup(i)'  style="min-width: auto;"  pButton icon="fa fa-minus">Remove</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</form>
<button class="add-remove-btn" pButton (click)='addOptionGroup()' icon="fa fa-plus">Add</button>

//ts
public countryOptions:any = [];
  public stateOptions:any = [];

  public countries = [];
  public states = [];

  public entityForm: FormGroup;
  public optionGroups: FormArray;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
    ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.entityForm = this.fb.group({
      optionGroups : this.fb.array([])
    });

    this.optionGroups = this.entityForm.get('optionGroups') as FormArray;

    this.getAllCountries();
    const initData = [
      {countryCode: "US", stateCode: "AZ", fileNumber: "AAA"},
      {countryCode: "CA", stateCode: null, fileNumber: null}
    ]

    this.initFormArray(initData)
  }


  public addOptionGroup(){
    const fa = this.entityForm.get('optionGroups') as FormArray;
    //fa.setValue("--Select--");
    fa.push(this.newOptionGroup());
  }

  public removeOptionGroup(index: number){

      const fa = this.entityForm.controls["optionGroups"] as FormArray;
    
      fa.removeAt(index);
    
      }

  onCountryChange(selectedCountry: string , formIndex : number) : void {
    console.log(selectedCountry);
    this.states[selectedCountry] = this.getStates(selectedCountry)
  }

  private newOptionGroup() {
    return new FormGroup({          
        country: new FormControl("--select--"),
        state: new FormControl("--select--"),
        place: new FormControl("GGG"),

    });
  }


  getStates(selectedCountry) {
    //API call

      switch(selectedCountry) {
        case "US" : 
          this.stateOptions =[
        {id: 14, state: "Alabama", code: "AL", countryCode: "US"},
        {id: 15, state: "Alaska", code: "AK", countryCode: "US"},
        {id: 17, state: "Arizona", code: "AZ", countryCode: "US"},
        {id: 18, state: "Arkansas", code: "AR", countryCode: "US"},
        {id: 19, state: "California", code: "CA", countryCode: "US"}
        ]
        break;

      case  "CA" :
        this.stateOptions =[{id: 37, state: "Marshall Islands", code: "MH", countryCode: "CA"},
        {id: 4, state: "New Brunswick", code: "NB", countryCode: "CA"},
        {id: 5, state: "Newfoundland and Labrador", code: "NL", countryCode: "CA"},
        {id: 53, state: "Northern Mariana Islands", code: "MP", countryCode: "CA"},
        {id: 6, state: "Northwest Territories", code: "NT", countryCode: "CA"}]
        break;    
      default: 
      this.stateOptions =[
        {id: 14, state: "Alabama", code: "AL", countryCode: "US"},
        {id: 15, state: "Alaska", code: "AK", countryCode: "US"},
        {id: 17, state: "Arizona", code: "AZ", countryCode: "US"},
        {id: 18, state: "Arkansas", code: "AR", countryCode: "US"},
        {id: 19, state: "California", code: "CA", countryCode: "US"}
        ]
        break;
    }
    return this.stateOptions;
  }

  initFormArray(initForm:any) {
    console.log(initForm);
    initForm.map((item, index) => {
      this.optionGroups.push(this.createForms(item, index));
    });
  }

  createForms(adresse, index): FormGroup {   
    const formGroup = new FormGroup({
        country: new FormControl(adresse.countryCode),
        state: new FormControl(adresse.stateCode),
        place: new FormControl(adresse.fileNumber)
      });
    this.onCountryChange(adresse.select1, index);
  return formGroup;
  }

  getAllCountries() {
    //API call
    this.countries = [{"country":"United States","countryCode":"US"},{"country":"Canada","countryCode":"CA"}]
  }
```